# Not able to set multiple connections in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to set multiple connections in Laravel application.

I tried using database.php is:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'reports_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
     'mysql1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'a2z'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
```

and .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=reports_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass


CL_DB_CONNECTION=mysql1
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=a2z
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Inside controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $ad= new Ad;

        $ad->setConnection('mysql1');
        $ad =  ad::get();
        echo $job;
      }
```

But I am not able to set up mysql1 connection.Can you please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: i think the code is correct but the error is in line $ad = $ad->get();

Comment: and also look at the @Shakti Phartiyal answer. you have to change names of you env variables to be different for each connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are actually using the same connection parameters both the time as you are using the same env values in your database.php:

Your .env file should contain something like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=reports_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass


TWO_DB_CONNECTION=mysql1
TWO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
TWO_DB_PORT=3306
TWO_DB_DATABASE=a2z
TWO_DB_USERNAME=root
TWO_DB_PASSWORD=root
```

and database.php should be something like this:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'reports_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
     'mysql1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('TWO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('TWO_DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('TWO_DB_DATABASE', 'a2z'),
        'username' => env('TWO_DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('TWO_DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
```